# WPF modal window as tool window in WinForms disappears

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this rather baffling situation. I have a WPF form `myForm` which I am displaying modally in a WinForm application (without using an ElementHost). Everything works fine if I use the default WindowStyle and it is shown in the taskbar. However now I don't want the form to show in the taskbar or contain the minimize button, therefore I have done the following:

```
MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
myForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
myForm.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
myForm.WindowStartupLocation =System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

Now, the wpf form displays as expected modally and without the minimize button. If I now select the "parent" winform application in the taskbar, the wpf form disappears and there doesn't seem to be any way of returning to it! I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760571/showdialog-makes-app-window-disappear-from-windows-alt-tab-list) which is similar but not the same (pure WPF application), so I can understand why the main app does not appear in the ALT+TAB menu, but can anyone tell me how I can return to the wpf form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem is that if the WPF ToolWindow gets pushed behind the main application or another application, you cannot bring the window forward at all right?

Comment: Have you tried setting the owner of the toolwindow? This should even work if you mix winforms and wpf. You can make this work with WindowsInteropHelper or calling SetParent using the winapi directly.

Comment: @CodingGorilla yes that's correct.

Comment: Owner is the problem.  A hard one, you don't have a Window to be the owner.  You must pinvoke SetWindowLongPtr() to set the owner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `WindowsInteropHelper` allows you to wrap a hosted WPF-form using a Winforms-form and set its parent as a Winforms control, which prevents the WPF form from disappearing (as also pointed out by dowhilefor and Hans Passant)

E.g.:

```
// Use the interop helper for the specified wpf window hosted by the win32 owner
WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfForm);
wih.Owner = this.someWin32FormsControl.Handle;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Winforms or WPF, this is the way Windows functions.  The only solution that I think you have is to wire up your modality; that is intercept the `Activated` event on  your Winforms form and if your WPF tool window is visible, bring that window forward and give it focus.