# ShowDialog with coupled Minimize makes app disapear in "Alt + Tab" List

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I've got a normal `MainWindow` with a Settings button.
When the Settings button is clicked, I want a separate Settings window to get opened modal.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //...

    // On Settings button click ...
    var settingsWindow = new SettingsWindow();
    settingsWindow.Owner = this;
    settingsWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Despite the fact, that the `SettingsWindow` is not only a small "Okay/Cancel" dialog, I want it to be modal (so I use `ShowDialog()`), because some configuration stuff needs to be completed before application flow continues. So `SettingsWindow` is a normal window with min/max/close buttons.

If the user minimizes the `SettingsWindow`, the `MainWindow` not only should get pushed to the background but should get minimized, too. This works properly by doing this:

```
public partial class SettingsWindow : Window
{
    // ...
    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStateChanged(e);
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized && Owner != null)
        {
            Owner.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Normal && Owner != null)
        {
            Owner.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
}
```

When the `SettingsWindow` and the `MainWindow` are minimized, I can get them back into the Normal WindowState by clicking with the mouse on the icon, but I cannot achieve this by using "Alt + Tab" because the application disapeared in this list. In the "Win-Key + Tab" list the app is still there.

Is there a posibility to keep the application in the "Alt + Tab" list? The `SettingsWindow.WindowStyle` is `SingleBorderWindow` so no `ToolWindow`.

I know, this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760571/showdialog-makes-app-window-disappear-from-windows-alt-tab-list), but the goal is a little different.

Comment: "If the user minimizes the SettingsWindow, the MainWindow not only should get pushed to the background but should get minimized, too." -- So your question is "I made my window not behave like a standard Windows window, and now it no longer behaves like a standard Windows window. How do I fix this?" You should probably re-think your design, although I'm curious to see if anyone can give a simple obviously correct answer.

Comment: As an example of a re-worked design, can you show the settings window as non-modal, but disable the controls on the main window until the settings window is closed? That would still allow the user to minimise, move, resize, etc. the main window as desired, but prevent any real actions.

Comment: The normal windows way would be using 'SettingsWindows.ShowDialog()'. This garants that the user finished work with SettingsWindows before he can continue with the MainWindow.

Comment: You'll need to set the dialog's ShowInTaskbar property to true to get it to show up in the Alt+Tab strip.